# Key error in dictionary when the values are in loop

Tags: python, dictionary

```
for k,v in final.items():
    print k,v
```

{'company': {'website': u'url', 'u_idr': 'f457', 'contact': [u'+6569071560'], 'company_name': u'name', 'social': {},email_domain': [u'name.com'],'email': u'1stdictionary'semail@name.com'}}

{'company': {'website': u'url', 'u_idr': 'b9cd6', 'social': {'twitter': u'url', 'facebook': u'url', 'instagram': u'url'}, 'contact': [u'+6596097753'], 'company_name': u'name', 'email_domain': [u'name.com'],'email': u'2stdictionary'semail@name.com'}}

I want to access the values of contact,email and social. Knowing that, this is a simple logic, but still it is not working fine,

Below is my code:

```
for k, v in final.items():
    print v[email]
```

I receive this error, leaving the 1st email from the 1st dictionary

> 1stdictionary'semail@name.com
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "untitled.py", line 229, in
>
> print v['email'] KeyError: 'email'

My desired output is I need to collect the values of email, contact and social

Comment: use `print final[k]` or directly `print v`

Comment: But I specifically need the value of contact, social and email. print v or final[k] prints the value part of the dictionary. @luoluo

Comment: Maybe you need `print v["email"]`. note the `"` means a `string` value for you.

Comment: enquiries@straitsconstruction.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 229, in <module>
    print v["email"]
KeyError: 'email'

Answer (score 2):

If you just want those three values then a loop is not required. Also you are doing it the wrong way `v[email]` is wrong because v is a value not a dict.

Simply

```
company = final['company']
contact, email, social = company[contact], company[email], company[social]
```

Comment: Thanks @KeithC for review

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated the input. Company is the key and the rest are the values.

Comment: Thanks @Zohaib ljaz. :)

Answer (score 0):

company dictionary may not has "email"

try this code

```
for k, v in final.items():
     print v.get("email")
```